# Можно ли обращаться к конкретным элементам RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview

У меня есть `RecyclerView`, который состоит из элементов `EditText`, как мне получать то, что вводит пользователь в `EditText`?

Всем заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обращаться можно (технически, при определённых условиях), однако это неправильный путь. Вам надо действовать так:

1. При изменении текста в EditText записывайте изменения в переменную, которая будет во фрагменте/активити. Для этого используйте `TextWatcher`, а во фрагмент/активити передавайте текст через интерфейс, реализованный в фрагменте/активити и переданный во ViewHolder
2. Передавайте записанные в п.1 значения во ViewHolder для восстановления состояния. Вы будете прокручивать список и данные, ранее введённые в EditText будут потеряны, если вы их ранее не соранили и не передали во ViewHolder.
3. Когда вам эти данные понадобятся - они уже будут в переменных активити/фрагмента.